# Happy New Year?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, number-sequence, no-computers

Extend this infinite series by five more terms:

17, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 2, 3, 5, 11, 13, 17, 2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2

Comment: I assume WeatherVane's answer is correct, but I was hoping this puzzle would actually involve the prime numbers in an inherent way. Inspired by you, I've posted [a different puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84415/5373) which you may enjoy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is

> 3, 5, 7, 13, 17
>
>  When the prime numbers listed are replaced by their ordinal in the prime sequence, this relates to the OEIS sequence [A116369](https://oeis.org/A116369)  "Day of the week corresponding to Jan 01 of a given year." (n=0 for the year 2000)
>
>  The next five terms are 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 which are the ordinals of the prime numbers I gave.
>
>  The puzzle title is a hint!

Comment: need to give at least a indirect hint..never checked oeis..just thought about it yesterday while on my walk...expected it to be solved quickly