# Why did this prime-sequence puzzle not work?

Tags: mathematics, puzzle-creation, number-theory

While attacking [a recent puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84410/5373) (whose solution ended up being entirely different from what I was trying), I was inspired to create a [number-sequence](/questions/tagged/number-sequence) puzzle with a sequence $(p_n)$ of primes where the secret rule is

> $p_{n+1}$ is defined as the lowest prime factor of the number $2^{p_n}+1$.

Unfortunately, I couldn't turn this into a reasonable puzzle. So I'm posting a meta-puzzle about it instead: **can you see why this wouldn't make a good puzzle?** Specifically, why couldn't I generate a good sequence to put in the question?

Comment: It was great to see the teamwork on this one, as people inched closer to the full realisation/solution in successive answers :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Theorem:** The number $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ for any odd number $n$.
>  **Proof**: Set $n=2k+1$. Then modulo $3$ we have $$2^n+1 = 2^{2k+1}+1 = 2\cdot 4^k+1 \equiv 2\cdot1^k+1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$
>  which proves the theorem.
>
>  Since $2^n+1$ is odd for $n>0$, its lowest factor will be an odd prime. The sequence therefore will become 3 at the second step, and then remain $3$ afterwards.

Comment: Yep, there we go. That's the key discovery.

Comment: Did you nip my proof? Well played!

Comment: @El-Guest When I started writing my proof, I don't think you had cottoned on to the fact that the factor 3 occurs at all odd exponents, but by the time I submitted you had and were working on a proof yourself.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I would’ve beaten you if I wasn’t so hell-bent on using induction haha! Well done on the modular arithmetic, your proof is much cleaner than mine. +1

Answer (score 3):

> $p_{n+1}$ is defined as the lowest prime factor of the number $2^{p_n}+1$.

Let’s try something:

> Let $p_0 = 2$. Then $p_1$ is the lowest prime factor of $2^2 + 1 = 5$, so 5. Then $p_2$ is the lowest prime factor of $2^5 +!1 = 33$, so 3. Then $p_3$ is the lowest prime factor of $2^3 + 1 = 9$....which is 3 again! Looks like this sequence has an infinite repetition and converges to 3...

The question is,

> Is this true for any $p_0$? The fact of the matter is that we have a countable set of $p_n$, because the number of $p_n$ must be less than the number of integers $2^x + 1$ there are — and this is one-to-one with the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. It seems logical that at some point in the sequence of $p_n$, you’ll find a number divisible by 3. To avoid this, you’d essentially need to find a series of primes — quasi-Mersenne — where each continuing $2^{p_n} + 1$ is also prime. I don’t think that such a sequence exists...

Sample starting points:

> $p_0 = 2$. 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, ... 
>  (My favourite) $p_0 = 3$. 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ... 
>  $p_0 = 5$. 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, ... 
>  $p_0 = 7$. 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, ... (because of 129) 
>  $p_0 = 11$. 11, 3, 3, 3, 3, ... (because of 2049)....

Hmm....

> Does every $p_0 > 2$ converge to 3 within one step? @WeatherVane found that this is at least the case for $3 \leq p_0 \leq 61$. This is essentially saying for prime $p$, does $3 | 2^p + 1$? Further, for any odd natural number 2m+1, does $3 | 2^{2m+1} + 1$? Let’s see...this is true iff $3 | 2^{2m+1} - 2 = 2( 2^{2m} - 1)$ iff $3 | 2^{2m} - 1$ iff $3 | 2^{2m} - 4$.... *commences rambling*...

Let’s use

> Induction. We seem to have exhaustively proved base cases above. Then, assume that for some odd integer $n = 2m + 1$, $3 | 2^n + 1$. Then consider $p$ = 2m + 3, the next odd integer. Does $3 | 2^p + 1 = 2^{2m+3} + 1 = 4(2^{2m+1}) + 1$? Well, if $3 | 2^n + 1 = 2^{2m+1} + 1$, then $3 | 4(2^{2m+1} + 1)$. So $3 | 4(2^{2m+1}) + 4$. It must therefore also divide 3 less than that, and so $3 | 4(2^{2m+1}) + 1 = 2^{2m+3} + 1 = 2^p + 1$. We have therefore shown that the inductive hypothesis does indeed imply the inductive conclusion. By induction, therefore, $3|2^n+1$ for any positive odd integer $n$.

It naturally follows that

> Any starting prime number greater than 2 is a positive odd integer, and so for any $p_0 > 2$, we must have $p_n = 3 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since we have shown that $p_0 = 2$ converges to 3 within 2 steps, for any prime $p_0$, $p_n = 3 \forall n \geq 2$. This is why **there is no sequence (not even the hypothetical prime ladder postulated above) which is suitable for puzzling, because every prime sequence (without restriction) converges to 3 infinitely.** $\square$

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 37 seconds....

Comment: Which is a prime number.  How suitable.

Comment: Please see my amended answer having read yours.

Comment: Did you just throw it into a computer? Thanks for the computation — good to see that the hypothesis appears correct so far, at least @WeatherVane! Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, the easy ones $ \lt 2^{64}$. But actually, there is not always just *one* other prime factor.

Comment: Nice! I think I finally proved it though!

Comment: Oh! And I went up to $2^{7919}$ the first 1000 primes, true for all except $2^2$.

Comment: And now all odd powers up to $2^{99999}$.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure... partial

> Because some $2^{x} + 1$ are prime numbers: no factors.
>  For example $x = 8$

Edit:

> The above wasn't well thought, because $8$ cannot be a *lowest* factor.
>
>  But from @El-Guest's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/84416/51581), I found that
>
>  For *every* prime $3 \le x \le 61$, $2^{x} + 1$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

I think

> It looks as if you would get stuck at the number 3

because

> often 3 is going to be the lowest prime factor and $2^3+1=9$ which again gives 3